# I change the footer on Magento, but it only apply to the homepage

Tags: magento, footer

I　am using Magento, I change the footer by click "CMS/Static Blocks/Footer Links", but this change only apply to the home page, how do I make this change apply to the whole website?

Comment: is the footer hardcoded in the template you use?

Comment: Only the homepage is the code I write, the rest pages' footer is not.

Comment: the URL is http://dompetroff.com/   you can see the homepage's facebook button is different from the rest pages' footer, like about us page

Comment: Enable Template Hints and check what template is loaded on other pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your homepage can youse one layout, and all of other pages can use different layout. For example: homepage has 1-column, and other pages - 2columns-left. First - go to CMS->pages->homepage. Open design tab and check, wich layout use your homepage. Second, in design tab, in xml-update can be overrided a homepage  template. So you will code only home page template, and it will no affect other pages. If so - figure out, wich template is used on other pages (f.e. 2-columns-left.phtml), and change it too.